# Python Bottle and Polymer Paper Elements

Tags: javascript, python, polymer, bottle, paper-elements

I have a website with the following features. A dozen of forms where the user fill the inputs, and through Javascript I apply formulas to calculate and return new content to the user. I use Python Bottle for user register and auto fill the forms from the backend and the database. However, I am not satisfied with the design and I am looking for something new.

I found the Polymer Paper Elements and I really like it. It would be great to desktop, tablets and mobiles without a lot of effort on responsive. But, I have a few questions:

1. Python Bottle use `{{parameter}}` to pass variables from backend to frontend. I saw on Polymer tutorials that they use the same symbol `{{parameter}}` (double brackets) for dynamic change on variables. Will I have any problem since both Bottle and Polymer use the same way?
2. Have you seen any website with Polymer and Adsense? Since I use Adsense, I am not sure if the aesthetic would be nice with the Paper Elements.
3. Do you have any great example of Polymer Paper Elements of a website to share?

Answer (score 0):

- The [mustache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mustache_%28template_system%29) delimiters are hardcoded in [SimpleTemplate](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/_modules/bottle.html#SimpleTemplate) so you cannot change that without modifying Bottle source code .  But there are a lot of alternative template engines that allow you to configure delimiters or have other delimiter characters .

  You can start with [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/) Templates which lets you to change its delimiter characters and bottle provides a nice `@jinja2_view` 
  decorator that makes it easy to use .

  ```
  from bottle import jinja2_view, route

  @route('/', name='home')
  @jinja2_view('home.html', template_lookup=['templates'])
  def home():
      return {'title': 'Hello world'}
  ```
- If you are concerned about AdSense integration with Polymer , you should check out the [adsense component](https://github.com/kessiler/google-adsense) .

  - Install it with bower :
    `$ bower install google-adsense --save`
  - Import Web Components polyfill and Adsense element :

    `<script src="bower_components/platform/platform.js"></script>`
    `<link rel="import" href="bower_components/google-adsense/dist/google-adsense.html">`
  - use it : `<google-adsense></google-adsense>`

Comment: I haven't worked with Jinja2 for the last year, but as I can remember, it uses the same delimiters for the parameters `{{param}}`, but different for the python code in HTML `{% if %}`